# How to fix cross site request forgery vulnerability in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Getting issue for below line:

```
serviceResponse. post=$http.get(xyz).then(function(resp)
return resp. data;
```

Need your help to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question, describe the issue and include error messages/logs/output? Include a little more code than you have since it doesn't appear to be syntactically correct.

Comment: I have scan the code using fortify audit tool and getting csrf vulnerability issue for below code :=                                                                         fetchInfoFromSeviceResponse.all=function() { fetchInfoFromServiceResponse.post=$http.get(user_role_url).then(function(resp) { return resp.data;}

Comment: Try https://www.information-age.com/how-to-fix-the-csrf-vulnerability-in-popular-web-frameworks-123484913/ and https://vitalflux.com/angular-2-how-to-secure-apps-from-csrfxsrf-attack/ for some ideas.